# Bootstrap carrousel z-index problems

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser, z-index

i have problems with bootstrap slider.
Below is an image, how it should look like (firefox version).
The problem is, that even though it is working in firefox,
in edge and chromium (other browsers perhaps too, not tested) is the content of slider covered by transparent black instead of being on top of it.
I tried to fix it, but i didnt managed to make it work properly.

fiddle:
js used:

```
bootstrap.min.js
jquery
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p0b77ksg/

Image:
[Left: edge, right: firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSOX1.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Your image has arrows, your fiddle has dots. Need transparency and z-index applied to what exactly?

Comment: @designarti : It depends on resolution, if small, it turns on dots instead of arrows. try enlarging it. I need apply z-index to the text inside of the slider, so that it would not be covered.